# how to replace dbk,depb,epcg,nfei with Demo[i]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is my code i want to replace dbk,depb,epcg,nfei with Demo[i]

```
        string Test = ddlExim.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(3);
        txtEximDesc.Text = ddlExim.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(3);
        string[] Demo = ddlExim.SelectedValue.Split(',');

            DBK.Style.Add("display", "none");
            DEPB.Style.Add("display", "none");
            EPCG.Style.Add("display", "none");
            NFEI.Style.Add("display", "none");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (Demo[i] == "DEPB")
                {
                    DEPB.Style.Add("display", "table-row");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Would adding a "please" be such a burden?

Comment: @AndreiV Would it make a difference?

Comment: I think "please" fits in the same category as "hi", "thank you", etc. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @dcastro, I'm not arguing for a highly polite community but I will invest my time in solving (polite) requests rather than solving "orders". I do agree with not using _hi_, _thanks_ etc. but bear in mind that the majority of people who add them do so automatically. Do you say _hi_ to your colleagues every time you pass them by on the hallway or office? And do you say _please_ every time you ask them for help? It's not such a big deal but it makes one hell of a difference.#

Comment: @AndreiV Why is it an order? The lack of a "please" doesn't make it an order. If it sounds like an order because of the way it was phrased, please remember that english is most likely not the OP's first language. Furthermore, the time you spend solving a question isn't just helpful to the OP, it's helpful to any future readers. You're not "serving" one individual, you're serving a community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly then I think the simplest way would be adding a switch case. Check the code below. Please elaborate your question if this is not what you meant.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Demo.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (Demo[i].ToLower())
            {
                case"dbk":
                    DBK.Style.Add("display", "table-row");
                    break;

                    //And so on

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

OR

mark `runat="server"` to the table element inside which these tablerows are present ("tbl" in my example) and then try the following code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Demo.Length; i++)
    {
        (tbl.FindControl(Demo[i]) as HtmlTableRow).Style.Add("display", "table-row");
    }
```

Of course you need to add the following namespace.

```
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to reduce my code length.
like that"" Demo[i].Style.Add("display", "table-row"); ""
this code doesnt need if and switch case statements.

Comment: Check my updated answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: no boss gettting same error 
dbk,depb,epcg--->these are row id<tr id="DBK" runat="server"></tr>
<tr id="DEPB" runat="server"></tr>
<tr id="EPCG" runat="server"></tr>

Comment: Check my updated answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: not working boss..
need help please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477103/please-help-i-need-to-replace-row-id-with-array-string-in-runtime

Comment: please visit above link

Comment: Check my updated answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: samar thanks for your help..
i got the output 
(MenuTable.FindControl(Demo[i]) as HtmlTableRow).Style.Add("display", "table-row");