# How to replace row id with array string at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Design Code

```
<tr id="DEPB" runat="server"></tr>

<tr id="DEPB" runat="server"></tr>

<tr id="DEPB" runat="server"></tr>
```

Behind Code

```
 string Test = ddlExim.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(3);
        txtEximDesc.Text = ddlExim.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(3);
        string[] Demo = ddlExim.SelectedValue.Split(',');
        try
        {
            DBK.Style.Add("display", "none");
            DEPB.Style.Add("display", "none");
            EPCG.Style.Add("display", "none");
            NFEI.Style.Add("display", "none");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (Demo[i] == "DEPB")
                {
                    Demo[i].Style.Add("display", "table-row");
                }
                else if (Demo[i] == "EPCG")
                {
                    EPCG.Style.Add("display", "table-row");
                }
                else if (Demo[i] == "DBK")
                {
                    DBK.Style.Add("display", "table-row");
                }
                else if (Demo[i] == ".")
                {
                    NFEI.Style.Add("display", "table-row");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Message = ex.Message;
        }
```

i want to replace DEPB,EPCG,DBK with `Demo[i]` like below but getting **error: "String doesnt contain a defnition for style".**

```
Demo[i].Style.Add("display", "table-row");
```

Comment: can you explain why do  you want to replace the ids of your tr  with your array

Comment: because if statments are not needed
Demo[i].Style.Add("display", "table-row");

Comment: show me what is `Demo` ? how did you declared it ?

Comment: What i understood by reading your code is Demo[] is a string array in which you have added the ids, now you are looping some how to set some style on your tr. But it is not clear what you are trying to achieve post your complete code with the exact problem.

Comment: string[] Demo = ddlExim.SelectedValue.Split(',');

Comment: you have used a string, an arrya nad textbox value to do some substring , what are you trying to achieve through this substinrg and spilt. what is the problem you are facing

Comment: what's in `ddlExim.SelectedValue` ? You have more information to show us !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark `runat="server"` to the table element inside which these tablerows are present ("tbl" in my example) and then try the following code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Demo.Length; i++)
    {
        (tbl.FindControl(Demo[i]) as HtmlTableRow).Style.Add("display", "table-row");
    }
```

Of course you need to add the following namespace.

```
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Demo` is an array of string, hence `Demo[i]` is a string and string doesn't have property `Style`. This line look like an outlier compared to other if's content :

```
Demo[i].Style.Add("display", "table-row");
```

I guess it should be as follow instead :

```
DEPB.Style.Add("display", "table-row");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to cat Demo[i] to webcontrol

Comment: what are you trying to tell in this answer is not at all clear